# NetBeans 8.2 : Node JS project showing error on "node_modules" folder

Tags: node.js, netbeans-8.2

I configured everything perfectly on my IDE. But it is still showing an error. "node_modules" > "less"

Comment: Can you please put the full error in your post; there is insufficient information currently. Since you are using and IDE, you should also mention _which_ IDE you are using, and whether you have this problem running npm on the command line as well.

Comment: Link : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3giUSvRjPc" In this video there is an error that on Node jS project call "Hello Express". The error is showing  in "node_modules". That is my problem bro.

Comment: I can give you some images from my project, that showing errors. Can you please give me your mail ?

Answer (score 0):

> npm -i less -S

try this command

Comment: Bro, i try that. but i dont know what to do after that. Because im new to Node JS. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I can give you some images from my project, that showing errors. Can you please give me your mail ?

Comment: Ill send you the images.

Comment: @AfzalHassan any issue still there?